# Cannot remove (or reinstall) Spotify or any other program

Tags: apt, package-management, spotify

I had install Spotify a while back but since deleted some folder belonging to it (accidental rm- rf operation - sh*t happens).

I now can't install any software at all via apt-get (pip works fine)

When I run

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

I get the following

```
>(Reading database ... 586089 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../spotify-client_1%3a0.9.11.26.g995ec04.78-1_amd64.deb ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/spotify-client.prerm: 9: cd: can't cd to /opt/spotify/spotify-client
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: 9: cd: can't cd to /opt/spotify/spotify-client
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/spotify-client_1%3a0.9.11.26.g995ec04.78-1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 2
/var/lib/dpkg/info/spotify-client.postinst: 5: cd: can't cd to /opt/spotify/spotify-client
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/spotify-client_1%3a0.9.11.26.g995ec04.78-1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

It says it cannot cd into /opt/spotify/spotify-client (because that's what I deleted)

Fix suggestions?

I am more than happy to entirely remove Spotify

I have tried all of the following

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get install [some package] fails
```

All fail because it can't find the spotify-client

I have tried to remove it from /etc/apt/sources.list but no cigar

Comment: I'm not sure for the result but you can try to download http://repository.spotify.com/pool/non-free/s/spotify/spotify-client_0.9.11.26.g995ec04.78-1_amd64.deb and install it via `sudo dpkg -i`

Comment: Tried it:
dpkg: error processing archive spotify-client_0.9.11.26.g995ec04.78-1_amd64.deb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system tries to install Spotify. Create a directory `/opt/spotify/spotify-client`, owned by root, with permissions 755 and try again. If you accentally also deleted `/opt/spotify`, do the same for that directory. Then repeat `sudo apt-get -f install`, and `sudo apt-get remove spotify`.

Comment: Tried:
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: 9: /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: ./unregister.sh: not found

Comment: The package is probably considered to be in an inconsistent state. Try `sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq spotify-client`.

Comment: dpkg: warning: package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting a removal

--also-- 

subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
/var/lib/dpkg/info/spotify-client.postinst: 5: /var/lib/dpkg/info/spotify-client.postinst: ./register.sh: not found

Comment: Strange: the `--force-remove-reinstreq` is supposed to take care of that. As a last resort, backup your file `/var/lib/dpkg/status`, open it in an editor, delete everything from `Package: spotify-client` to the next blank line. You will end up with some unused files and packages, but you may be able to go ahead with `apt-get`.

Answer (score 0):

Download the deb file for spotify and convert it to a `tar.gz` archive using:

```
alien --to-tgz spotify*.deb
```

Uncompress and untar the archive:

```
tar xzf spotify*.tgz
```

Copy `opt/spotify` folder to original location (`/opt/spotify`).